# Ctor-initializer for a class doesn't call to the appropriate constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm playing with construting/destructing object. Here is what I've tried http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff17cc5649897430:

```
#include <iostream>

struct B{
    B(){ std::cout << "B()" << std::endl; }
    B(int){ std::cout << "B(int)" << std::endl; }
};

struct A : virtual B
{
    int B;
    A(int a) : B(a) { std::cout << "A(int)" << std::endl; }
} a(10);

int main()
{
}
```

The program output is

```
B()
A(int)
```

Why? I explicitly specify the constructor of the class `B` to be invoked in the *ctor-initializer*.

Comment: You have an `int B;` member variable. THAT is getting constructed with your `int` argument but only AFTER the `B` base class is default initialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `B(a)` is constructing the `B` member variable. Name your variables better and you'll see what you want to see.